# Wanting To Optionally Add JavaScript code using Gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mocking

I've got a gulpfile.js that bundles using browserify and I want to be able to optionally add one line to one of my javascript files based on a variable like useMock.  Below is my GulpFile.js build step

```
function bundle (bundler) {
return bundler
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

The last line of the file below is the one I want to optionally include.

```
module.exports = require('angular')
    .module('AngularUApp', [
        require('angular-ui-router'),
        require('angular-sanitize'),
        require('../../base'),
        require('./home'),
        require('./speaker'),
        require('./author')
    ])
    .config(enableHtml5Mode)
    .name;

enableHtml5Mode.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];
function enableHtml5Mode($locationProvider) {
    console.log('enableHtml5Mode');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

// I want to optionally include this from my gulpfile.js
require('../mock');
```

I want to be able to have a production and dev build where the dev includes the extra line and production does not. If there is a better more recommended way to  do this, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.  Using the browserify api itself from this link:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

```
var combinedArgs = merge(watchify.args, { debug: true });
var b = browserify(baseDir,combinedArgs);
b.add('angu/mock');
var watcher = watchify(b);
```

I had a problem earlier because I forgot the relative directory from gulp is different than from inside the JavaScript itself.